# GCD function in scheme48 from bare metal

Tags: algorithm, scheme48

I'm trying to write a GCD function in scheme48 from scratch, but keep getting the the function to enter into an infinite loop. I believe the logic is correct - apparently I'm missing something. Any help would be great. Also I can not use built-in functions like `abs()` in remainder in my solution.

```
(define (mygcd a b)
(cond ((equal? a b) a)
  ((> a b) (mygcd (- a b)(b))
  (else (mygcd (a)(- b a))))
```

Comment: Missing test for b == 0.

Comment: where would i put that?